# Working with checkbox input in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have the following check box in my form. The form uses from model binding:

```
 {!! Form::model($user, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['AccountController@update']]) !!}
       {!! Form::hidden('text_only_email', false) !!}
       <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                  {!! Form::checkbox('text_only_email', 'true') !!} 
                  I'd prefer to receive emails as text only
            </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
           {!! Form::label('name', 'Name *', ['class' => '']) !!}
           {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
           {!! errors_for('name', $errors) !!}
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Update</button>
  {!! Form::close() !!}
```

My controller action is as follows:

```
 public function update(AccountRequest $request)
 {

       Auth::user()->update($request->all());

       flash()->success('Details updated');

       return redirect('account');
 }
```

In my user model I have set this as a mass assignment field as well:

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'text_only_email'];
```

Basically this is the issue, If I check the checkbox and leave the name field blank (name field is mandatory), I get the postback error as expected and the hidden input field gets set to `true`. Now lets say for some reason I decide to uncheck the checkbox after the postback before I re-submit or lets say it's an  update form rather than a create form, in which case the hidden field value will remain set to `true` hence the form submission doesn't work as expected.

The only way I can think of how to make this work is by using some jquery to toggle the hidden value when the user checks or unchecks the checkbox.

I am aware that it can be achieved on the server side by using something like this: `$request->input('text_only_email', false)` but I was wondering if anyone has come across a more elegant solution so that I dont need to keep checking on the serverside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to fix by adding a manual hidden input field instead of using the form builder for generating it: `<input name="text_only_email" value="" type="hidden">`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two fields with the same name, `text_only_email` is a hidden  input as well as a checkbox

Comment: Checkboxes if unchecked don't send any value to the server. Hence the above is a trick to ensure some value is sent back to the server.